# Prestashop and Smarty

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

i have problem with smarty templating on Prestashop.

I want to echo product description with html tags (wysiwyg) but it gives me string with striped html tag or nothing.

```
{$product.description_short|unescape|strip_tags:false}
```

`unescape` and `strip_tags:false` not change anything. String is still striped. Using only `{$product.description_short}` display nothing.

i try to use `{php} {/php}` but then everything i get is 500 error.

This is on listing .tpl

On single product view description works fine with that code `{$product->description_short}`

Comment: Which version of prestashop are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what do you want, have you tried this:

```
{$product.description_short|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}
```